# div jump after it slide down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I create a new page using HTMl and I whant when user clicks on one of my Links ,one div slide down at the bottom of it. the problem is when I using this code in my page it silde down in left side of my header and then it jump beneath my link.I save the code in `jSfiddle` :

http://jsfiddle.net/GMSvk/1/
in `jsFiddle` it jump up after slide down .please help me to solve this.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `clear:both` to `#Specifications`

http://jsfiddle.net/GMSvk/3/

Answer (score 0):

I just used a `<br />` tag, and it worked. :)

```
  </div>
</div>
<br />
  <div id="Specifications">
     wq  we  q
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `overflow:hidden` on `.topLeftBand` which should fix the problem.

```
.topLeftBand {
    overflow:hidden;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited you code please check - http://jsfiddle.net/GMSvk/4/

fixed jumping issue , align issue.  Please reply me if you have any doubt